# Sum database on location and time

Tags: python, database

I have problem with the for loop in Python. I want to sum these data based on time and location, without pandas. This data is in the MySQL database (mysql workbench):

```
 Time     No_of_people      Location
----------------------------------------
07:00         20           Liberty City
07:15         25           Liberty City
07:30         20           Liberty City
07:45         30           Liberty City
08:00         21           Liberty City
...
07:00         10           San Andreas
07:15         15           San Andreas
07:30         20           San Andreas
07:45         25           San Andreas
08:00         30           San Andreas
```

Now I want it to be like:

```
 Time     No_of_people      Location
----------------------------------------
07:00       116            Liberty City
08:00       120            Liberty City
...
07:00       100            San Andreas
```

This is currently what I have done:

views.py:

```
def getData(request):

    api = 'http://localhost:8000/api/myData/'
    response = requests.get(api)
    myData = response.json()

    time = []
    no_of_people = []
    location = []    

    for hourly in myData:
        time.append(hourly['time'])
        no_of_people.append(hourly['no_of_people'])
        location.append(hourly['location'])

hour = []
    for x in range(7,24):
        hour.append(x)

uniqueLocation=[]

    for x in location:
        if x not in uniqueLocation:
            uniqueLocation.append(x)

    for uniqueIndex in uniqueLocation:
        for x in hour:
            sum =0
            for index, t in enumerate(time):
                x_time = t.split(":")[0]
                if int(x_time) == x and uniqueIndex == location[index]:
                    sum += no_of_people[index]
            print(str(sum))

    json_obj = {
        "time": time,
        "no_of_people": no_of_people,
        "location": location
    }
    return JsonResponse(data=json_obj)
```

Comment: instead of three lists `time`, `no_of_people`, `location` you could use one list `rows` and keep items `[hourly['time'], hourly['no_of_people'], hourly['location']]`. You could also add `hourly['time'][:2]` to get hour.

Comment: `uniqueLocation = set(location)` - if you don't need to keep original order of locations.

Comment: Why are you bothering with JSON? Python can query databases too

Comment: What's wrong with pandas? How about just numpy or Dask?

Comment: @furas I'll give it a try.. thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm trying to understand "original" python.

Comment: You mean the standard library? Use sqlite https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html or skip the rest api https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or implement your logic within the API as a separate route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group by the location, therefore I suggest you aim for this format, which is easier to visualize, and then try to build the table output from there (for each city, for each time, print hour and people/hr)

```
[
  {'location' : 'Liberty City', 'times': [{'hour' : '7:00', 'people' : 116}, ...]},
  ... 
]
```

When working with almost any database, try to create a class per object (row, table, bucket, relationship, (insert database term here), etc). You can then isolate logic here rather than clutter the main function

```
class Location:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name 
        self.times = list()

    def __str__(self):
        s = ['{}\t{}\t{}'.format(k, t[k], self.name) for t in self.times for k in t.keys()] 
        return '\n'.join(s) 

    def add_time(self, hour, people):
        existing_people_for_hour = None
        for t in self.times:  # loop existing times, looking for the hour 
            existing_people_for_hour = t.get(hour) 
            if existing_people_for_hour is not None:
                t[hour] += people
                break  # found the hour to update, so break the loop
        if existing_people_for_hour is None:  # if the hour was never found, add to the times list 
            self.times.append({hour : people})
```

With that in place, use a dictionary to group on the location value and you should be able to print them in the end

```
locations = dict()
for d in myData:
    # parse each value out 
    hour = d['time'][:2] + ':00'
    p = int(d['no_of_people']) 
    loc = d['location']

    # get the location from the map, if exists, else create new one 
    l = locations.get(loc, Location(loc))
    l.add_time(hour, p)  # add the people for the time 

    locations[loc] = l  # upsert the new location 

for l in locations.values():
    print(l)
```

#### Output

```
07:00   95  Liberty City
08:00   21  Liberty City
07:00   70  San Andreas
08:00   30  San Andreas
```

Comment: is there supposed to be a comma between `hour` and `people` in `def add_time(self, hour people):`? Also, I got an error `t[hour] += people  # if found, it already has a value
KeyError: '07:00'`

Comment: Yes, good catch. And I made a edit to the answer which I think fixes that

Comment: This doesn't work. For some reason, the sum doesn't adds up. this is the output:
`Liberty City     07:00     20
San Andreas  07:00     10`
it doesn't show 08:00 as well

Comment: Well, I didn't exactly test this (nor did you show your actual JSON data). I don't suppose you've learned how to debug code on your own?

Comment: yes, i'm new to python and I've mentioned it on top, but someone edited my question.

Comment: You have a table, not the actual data from the localhost address

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but when i `print(json_obj)` i got: _07:00, 07:00,07:00,07:00..... 23:45,23:45,23:45, 20, 10, 40, 50...._

Comment: thanks! is there a way to change it into a json format though? or rather how can retrieve it from views.py

Comment: Yes, change the `__str__` function to return JSON. Or write your own to_json function. .. I suggest you make a new post if you have issues with that

Comment: ok, I have managed to change it to JSON. but can I just ask why we do not need 'no_of_people' in `def __init__(self, name):`. Also, do you mind explaining the format in `def __str__(self):`? I am abit lost. sorry, I'm new to both Python and Django

Comment: 1) Function and variables names are not important. The number of people is a calculated metric using pre-existing information and it changes based on the input to the `add_time` function 2) https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__  Try changing it to `return "Name - " + self.name`, and other variations. See how that affects the output